# How to Unit test a method using Moqs which create session

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit

How to test a method which creates session inside the method. i using to do Unit test . when i call method using test case it was unable to create session inside method. can anyone please help me to create unit tests for my code below

```
public ActionResult InviteUser(string Id)
    {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
      {
        Session["verification_uid"] = Id; 
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account"); 
      }
      return View();
    }
```

i have tried with following code also but it not working

```
  [TestMethod]
        public void InviteUser_ExpectRedirectActionResultReturned()
        {
            //Arrange
            controller = new AccountController();

            var mockControllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
            var mockSession = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
            mockSession.SetupGet(s => s["verification_uid"]).Returns("123"); //somevalue
            mockControllerContext.Setup(p => p.HttpContext.Session).Returns(mockSession.Object);
            controller.ControllerContext = mockControllerContext.Object;

            var id = "1";
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["verification_uid‌​ID"] = "12";

            //Act
            var result = (RedirectToRouteResult)controller.InviteUser(id);

            //Assert
            result.RouteValues["action"].Equals("Index");
            result.RouteValues["controller"].Equals("Home");

            Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.RouteValues["action"]);
            Assert.AreEqual("Home", result.RouteValues["controller"]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put the setting of the session variable into a helper class, implementing an interface that gets passed into the class which you could mock in the unit test.

```
public MyClass 
{
    private readonly ISessionHelper _helper;

    public MyClass(ISessionHelper helper)
    {
        this._helper = helper;
    }

    public ActionResult InviteUser(string Id)
    {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
      {
        this._helper.SetSessionVariable("verification_uid", Id);
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account"); 
      }
      return View();
    }
}
```

Your helper would contain SetSessionVariable which does the setting.

Then, in your unit test, you mock `ISessionHelper`.

Comment: can we do without using service based architecture, because we are not using services in application . this is simple web based application

Comment: @CharanTejaKuta I'm not sure why you think this has anything to do with services. This is simply passing in the helper into the constructor of your class so it can be mocked.